# ASP.NET Create a specific culture with language code nb (Bokmål)

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture, country

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 website.

Why can't I create a specific culture for the language Bokmal like this:

```
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb");
```

Language "en" works fine, it results in "en-US". I thought that with "nb" I could do the same thing and get culture "nb-NO". But with "nb" i get the error:

> Culture nb is not supported.

I'll explain why I needed it.

I retrieved a list of cultures: "nl-NL", "nl-BE", "nb-NO", "fr-CH", "fr-FR"
Want I wanted was a unique list of languages with the default cultures. So I create a list with unique languages which results in "nl", "nb", "fr". Next thing I want the specific cultures but nb doesn't work. I wanted this because the unique list selected nl-BE instead of the default nl-NL.

But then I'll just stick with "nl-BE" when Dutch is selected and place the cultures in a unique cultures list. This list will result in "nl-BE", "nb-NO", "fr-CH".

Comment: What if you use nb-NO? On this page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx it gives you three options - no, nb-NO and nn-NO for the various dialects(?) for Norway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assume that there is a correspondence between language names and parent-child relationships between CultureInfo objects. The hierarchy also depends on Windows version.

According to the documentation for the [NLS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx), the "nb" culture exists on Windows 7, but not on Windows Vista.

On my Windows 7 machine, the culture hierarchy for Bokmål is, in child to parent order

- nb-NO
- nb
- no
- Invariant culture

In short, you should use the Parent property of the CultureInfo object, instead of doing string manipulations.

Comment: Usefull information, thanks. But with parent i keep the same problem: parent of be-NL is be, but creating a specific culture for be creates be-BY. So I don't think it is possible what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think you're confusing languages and countries. "be" means the language "Belarussian", not the country "Belgium". Also the culture describing "Dutch as it is spoken in Belgium" is nl-BE, not be-NL

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, i mean: parent of nl-BE returns "be", but from "be" I can't make nl-BE, CreateSpecificCulture("be") returns be-BY

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see why this is not working. These three names below gives me Correct Culture

Try:

```
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb-NO");
```

UnitTest:

```
        [Test]
    public void CultureTest()
    {
        var c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb-NO");

        Assert.AreEqual("Norwegian, Bokmål (Norway)",c.DisplayName);
        Assert.AreEqual("nb-NO", c.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("norsk, bokmål (Norge)", c.NativeName);

        var c2 =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb");

        Assert.AreEqual("Norwegian, Bokmål (Norway)", c2.DisplayName);
        Assert.AreEqual("nb-NO", c2.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("norsk, bokmål (Norge)", c2.NativeName);

        var c3 =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("NO");

        Assert.AreEqual("Norwegian, Bokmål (Norway)", c3.DisplayName);
        Assert.AreEqual("nb-NO", c3.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("norsk, bokmål (Norge)", c3.NativeName);


    }
```

Comment: I don't know why, I get an Argument Exception. I'm using ASP.NET 3.5.

Comment: And you have debugged and checked so you don´t passes empty string or some else silly misstake?

Comment: Apparantly it is machine dependent